# Serial correlation misunderstanding

Tags: variance, autocorrelation

A consequence of having serial correlation in a model is downward bias of the standard errors of the estimated coefficients. This means that t-scores are inflated or overestimated. However, does the variance *increase* or *decrease*? 
Common logic suggests that inflated t-scores result from a low / decreasing variance. Yet I can't seem to figure out why it would increase.

Comment: You say logic suggests it would decrease. Why then are you trying to figure out "why it would increase"?

Comment: because on a quiz i previously took, it was the only question i got wrong!

Comment: It would be important toknow if autocorrelation is positive or negative ...